# Can I develop Google Drive app with Java1.4?

Tags: google-drive-api

I am developing one app which run at java 1.4 envirment.
And i know that Google Drive sdk is released in Java1.5 or 1.6.
Could you tell me a method to resolve the above problem.

Answer (score 0):

Java 1.5 or higher is required by the Google API Java Client, as stated [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/).